# initramfs configuration fails new modules are added

Tags: linux, kernel, virtual-machine, kernel-modules

I'm trying to passtrought PCI via OMVF. [The manual](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Using_vfio-pci) states to

> That means adding, in this order, vfio, vfio_iommu_type1, vfio_pci and vfio_virqfd to mkinitcpio

and regenerate `initramfs` configuration afterwards. However, my system isn't booting afterwards. Removing the added modules and reconfiguring restores the system to my previous state.

Also, is there a way to check what is the cause of system not booting?

Answer (score 0):

If system not booting is cause from a misconfiguration.
On my slackware I use this procedure for pci passtrough
In this example we pass a simply pci card
the pci card must be NOT in use by your "host" system
so is OK if not supported by linux otherwise blacklist
the module in /etc/modprobe.d and reboot or try a rmmod
if possible.
Then detach from host with this command

```
virsh nodedev-detach pci_0000_06_00_0
```

in this example we use the pci address pci_0000_06_00_0
you can found your address using

```
lspci
```

Then pass the pci card with virt-manager or qemu